# Spinner getting the text fitting

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I have a Spinner and I want to fill this one with a currency array formatted like this:

USD - United States Dollar

This doesn't fit on a small screen, but it runs very ugly over the arrow of the spinner.

Is there a way to only show the 3 letter code of the currency for example on the main layout-screen, but once clicked on the Spinner and the list opens there is the full name format as mentioned above. Or even better, only show the text that fits, but don't run over the drop down arrow?

I now used substring to show only the first 3 characters, but this doesn't look so good (currencies hard to find).

Thanks!

EDIT:

I have the following layout:

```
 <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/currency"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
         android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:paddingRight="8dp" />
```

And this is what I don't want:

[image: Screenshot Spinner]

As you can see the text from the South African Rand goes right through the arrow of the spinner.

Comment: What layout are you using? You can use the `ellipsized` attribute to automatically truncate lines or you could use multiple lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SpinnerAdapter` you are using with your `Spinner` is called with `getView()` for the entries to go into the pop-up list and `getDropDownView()` for the entries to go into the `Spinner` itself. You are welcome to implement your `SpinnerAdapter` to have these be whatever you want. So, if you want the `getDropDownView()` to return something with the three-letter currency code, or using `android:ellipsize`, or whatever, you can do that.

Comment: Hi, ellipsize doesn't seem to work, any other options? Thanks